# How To compare 2 values in a loop in xslt

Tags: xslt

I have below Xml I have to perform XSLT transformation
I want to compare reference values in this uid CW with this uid xyz if the value matches then I have to create use the same values
otherwise i have to create new record on inside GUID='1'

Xml:

```
<Records count="1">
    <Record GUID="1">
    <Record GUID="abc" >
        <Record GUID="JK">
            <Item uid="CV">TAM</Item
            <Item uid="CW">
                <Reference>US</Reference>
            </Item>
        </Record>
    </Record>
    <Record GUID="abc">
        <Record  GUID="JK">
            <Item uid="CV">IISSP</Item>
            <Item uid="CW">
                <Reference>IIORC</Reference>
                <Reference>ISNAGEP</Reference>
            </Item>
        </Record>
    </Record>
     <Field guid="xyz">
        <Reference>US</Reference>
        <Reference>ACD</Reference>
        <Reference>FEAS</Reference>
    </Field>
    </Record>
 </Records>
```

Expected output is:

```xml
<Records>
    <Record GUID="1">
        <Record GUID="abc" >
            <Record GUID="JK">
                <Item uid="CV">TAM</Item
                <Item uid="CW">
                    <Reference>US</Reference>
                </Item>
            </Record>
        </Record>
    </Record>
    <Record GUID="1">
    <Record GUID="abc">
        <Record  GUID="JK">
            <Item uid="CV">IISSP</Item>
            <Item uid="CW">
                <Reference>IIORC</Reference>
                <Reference>ISNAGEP</Reference>
            </Item>
        </Record>
    </Record>
    </Record>
    <Record GUID="1">
        <Record GUID="abc" >
            <Record GUID="JK">
                <Item uid="CV">TAM</Item
                <Item uid="CW">
                    <Reference>ACD</Reference>
                </Item>
            </Record>
        </Record>
    </Record>
    <Record GUID="1">
        <Record GUID="JK">
                <Item uid="CV">TAM</Item
                <Item uid="CW">
                    <Reference>FEAS</Reference>
                </Item>
            </Record>
        </Record>
    </Record>   
 </Records>
```

```
How Can I write Xslt to acheive this please help me out
```

It should compare guid="xyz" values with uid="CW" if the value present thenit should print as it is like US is present then it should create new child record
but If value is not present then it should create new child record like ACD is not matched with value present in uid="CW" then it should create new child record in GUID="1"

it has to be one-to one mapping with GUID="1" and GUID="abc"

right now I have 3 records inside the GUID="1" in output I should get 4 records because ACD is not present

Could you please help me out?

Comment: Your input XML is not a well-formed XML document. Please edit your question and correct it. Also could you clarify your requirements? Your "expected output" contains the words "present" and "N/A" but neither occur in the input XML or the XSLT. How can they be "expected" in the output?

Comment: Rewrite your xml using some simple uid like uid-1, uid-2, content-1, … This will make it easier to understand (even for you) what you want to achieve.

Comment: Updated xml and output, I am new to xslt could you please me out

Comment: I suggest to take more effort in explaining your goals, and also show us what you did until now with your current outcome. Your current xslt  has i.e. `Value1 `, but that does not show up in your wanted outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question lacks logic between source-xml xslt and expected outcome , here some hints:

`/[some-filter]` is a illegale expression. It needs a location-step (mostly a `node()`) after `/`, which is only a kind of step-separator

A few examples:

- `*` = an element
- `Record` = a Record-element
- `node()` = any node()
- `/text()` = a text() node
- `/@*` = any attribute
- `/@id` = id-attribute

I.e. in your xslt-snippet change this

```
<xsl:for-each select="../[@guid= 'CW']">
```

to this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="../*[@guid= 'CW']">
```

Beware xslt and XPath are case-sensitive.
So this xml:

`<Record GUID="CW">`

wil not be selected by

`"*[@guid= 'CW']"`

the XPath:

`"../*[@guid= 'CW']"`

will select first the parent of the context and for that parent the children with a @guid-attriuut with the value CW. Is that what you want?

Comment: How can I loop through and add a condition then if the value found then i have come out of the loop